# How to prove this identity? $2\cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=1+\cos(x-y)$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$2\cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=1+\cos(x-y)$$

I started showing that the first part equals
$$\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos^2\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)+2\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)$$
I don't know how to continue.We have learnt the formulas for the double of an angle $\sin(a-b)$ and $\cos(a-b)$ and $\sin-\frac{\sin b}{\cos a}+\cos b$... so you can use them to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice, the following trig identity of double angle  $$\cos 2A=2\cos^2A-1$$ $$2\cos^2A=1+\cos 2A$$
now, setting $A=\frac{x-y}{2}$, we get
$$2\cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=1+\cos 2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$
$$2\cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=1+\cos(x-y)$$

Answer (score 1):

Just look here. Its quite simple

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $t = (x-y)/ 2$

$$ \cos 2 t = 2 \cos^2 t - 1 = \cos^2 t - \sin^2 t = 1 - 2 \sin^2 t $$
where you use the first one

Answer (score 0):

$$2\cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=1+\cos\left(x-y\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use $\cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(x-y))$:

---

$$2\cdot\frac{1+\cos(x-y)}{2}=1+\cos\left(x-y\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{2\left(1+\cos(x-y)\right)}{2}=1+\cos\left(x-y\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1+\cos(x-y)}{1}=1+\cos\left(x-y\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$1+\cos(x-y)=1+\cos\left(x-y\right)$$